# SSH then running command in the same line is different to running on different lines? Bash Script

Tags: macos, command-line, bash, ssh, bash-scripting

In a bash script, I'm trying to use ssh and osascript to display a notification on another mac. I can only manage to do this on the command line by first ssh-ing into the other mac then running

```
osascript -e 'display notification "You have received a message!"
```

then logging back out of that ssh. I need to be able to do this within a bash script. It doesn't matter if I have to type the password after running the script.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I advise you to copy your SSH identity to the remote machine, then it shouldn't prompt you for password.

1. do `ssh-keygen`:
2. Enter your password for the remote machine twice
3. do `ssh-copy-id -i /Users/user/.ssh/id_rsa` user@remotemachine
4. Enter your password for remote machine
5. Then, return to your local machine and do this `ssh user@remotemachine 'some-remote-command'`

It should execute *some-remote-command* on remote machine without asking for password. This can be used in scripts.